# How to know the first and last position on a string that is already on a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like this:

```
['MAR', 'TFFVGGNFK', 'LNGSK', 'QSIK', 'EIVER', 'LNTASIPENVEVVICPPATYLDYSVSLVK']
```

That used to be a string. I need to know the position of the first and last element of each string on the list to do something like:

```
0-2 MAR
3-11 TFFVGGNFK
...
```

How can i do it?

Comment: i don't understand the question. would 3-11 be the indexes of start and end of your second string **if** you concatenated your list?

Comment: yes it would. But i couldn't obtain any result with the function index... I'm a beginer, maybe i'm not aplying it right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo = ['MAR', 'TFFVGGNFK', 'LNGSK', 'QSIK', 'EIVER', 'LNTASIPENVEVVICPPATYLDYSVSLVK']

count = 0
for bar in foo:
    newcount = count + len(bar)
    print count, '-', newcount-1, bar
    count = newcount
```

Comment: Don't call a variable `string`.

Comment: D'oh, forgot about the `string` module. Changing it.

Comment: It's `str` in Python, and the `string` module is nearly useless. It's a wash.

Comment: @millimoose The `string` module still has it's legitimate uses - mainly it's constants (`string.alphabet` et al).

Answer (score 4):

Python 3 solution, using [`itertools.accumulate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> a = ['MAR', 'TFFVGGNFK', 'LNGSK', 'QSIK', 'EIVER', 'LNTASIPENVEVVICPPATYLDYSVSLVK']
>>> starts = [0] + list(accumulate(map(len, a)))
>>> starts
[0, 3, 12, 17, 21, 26, 55]
>>> pairs = [(l,r-1) for l,r in zip(starts, starts[1:])]
>>> pairs
[(0, 2), (3, 11), (12, 16), (17, 20), (21, 25), (26, 54)]
```

Remember that because of how slicing works in Python having `(0,3)` is usually more useful than `(0, 2)`, but I'll assume you have your reasons.

Comment: Elegant, if not necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 2):

As you wanted, in a method:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
lst = ['MAR', 'TFFVGGNFK', 'LNGSK', 'QSIK', 'EIVER', 'LNTASIPENVEVVICPPATYLDYSVSLVK']

def indexes(l):
    start = 0
    indexes = OrderedDict()
    for i in l:
        end = start+len(i)-1
        indexes[i] = (start, end)
        start = end+1
    return indexes

print indexes(lst)
>>> 
OrderedDict([('MAR', (0, 2)), ('TFFVGGNFK', (3, 11)), ('LNGSK', (12, 16)), ('QSIK', (17, 20)), ('EIVER', (21, 25)), ('LNTASIPENVEVVICPPATYLDYSVSLVK', (26, 54))])
```

But I would change the indexes to be without the "offset" and remove the `-1` and `+1` that you see in the method.

Comment: +1: This is basically the naive equivalent of DSM's answer, so it makes the algorithm clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list = ['MAR', 'TFFVGGNFK', 'LNGSK', 'QSIK', 'EIVER', 'LNTASIPENVEVVICPPATYLDYSVSLVK']
lenlist = []
for s in list:
    lenlist.append(len(s))
```

Now the list `lenlist` will contain the length  of each string. From here you can use a `for` loop to get the beginning and end:

```
belist = [] # list containing beginning & end
for i in range(len(lenlist)):
    belist.append(0)
    for j in range(i):
        belist[i].append(lenlist[j])
    belist[i] = str(belist[i]) + '-' + str(lenlist[i])
```

I think this should work :)

By the way, your beginning and end will be separated by a `-`, to put them in a list instead, replace the line `belist[i] = str(belist[i]) + '-' + str(lenlist[i])` with `belist[i] = (belist[i], lenlist[i])`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you have to join your list :

```
text = ''.join(myList)
```

then, you only need to `index` it :

```
pos = text.index("MAR")
value = (pos, pos + len("MAR"))
```